# Как объявить глобальный класс в PHP?

Tags: php

Как объявить глобальный класс в PHP?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В PHP классы глобальны по умолчанию, лишь в PHP 7 появляется понятие анонимного класса. Поэтому достаточно просто объявить класс при помощи ключевого слова class

```
class Cls {}
```

Возможно речь идет об автозагрузке класса? Т.е. механизме который позволяет загружать классы в только в том случае, если они реально вызываются и без использования явных конструкций типа `require_once`? В этом случае следует поместить класс в пространство имен и папку, которая будет соответствовать этому пространству. Имя файла должно совпадать с именем класса. Например, путь `php7/cls.php`

```
namespace PHP7;
class Cls {}
```

Тогда в файле вызова достаточно вызывать функцию `spl_autoload_register()` и класс будет доступен для использования

```
spl_autoload_register();
$page = new PHP7\Cls();
```

Если хотите, использовать класс без пространства имен функции `spl_autoload_register()` следует передать функцию, которая сообщит механизм поиска вашего класса

```
spl_autoload_register(function($classname){
  // Тут свой механизм поиска
  require_once(__DIR__ . "/$classname.php");
});
```

Comment: Большое спасибо Вам за ответ.